# Graphviz with java

Tags: java, graphviz

I have a class as below:

```
public class MyTasks{
    private String taskId;
    private String taskName;
    private List<MyTasks> inDependencies;
    private List<MyTasks> outDependencies;

    \\ getters and setters here
}
```

Now in my main method, I have `List` of `MyTasks` objects.

e.g. `taskId` one is dependent on `taskId` two which in turn is dependent on `taskId` three and four.

I want to use GraphViz to output this list as a dependency diagrams showing relationships between various MyTasks. How do I import the Graphviz API for Java? I'm wondering about maybe a language binding or something similar. The solution to my problem cannot include installing Graphviz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that doesn't use jars (which is either a benefit or a drawback depending what you are trying to accomplish).

I've used code something like this to turn a list of nodes into a graphviz formatted dot file.

```
private String OPEN_GRAPH = "digraph G { \n";
private String NODE = "{0} [label='{1}']; \n";
private String EDGE = "{0} -> {1}; \n";
private String CLOSE_GRAPH = "} \n";

public void format(Appendable sb) throws IOException {
    sb.append(OPEN_GRAPH);

    //Render nodes
    for (Node node : graph.getNodes().values()) {
        sb.append(MessageFormat.format(NODE, node.getId(), node.getName()));

        //Render edges for node
        for (String targetEdge : node.getEdges()) {
            sb.append(MessageFormat.format(EDGE, node.getId(), targetEdge));
        }
    }

    sb.append(CLOSE_GRAPH);
}
```

You can use graphviz's 'dot' command to turn your file into an image.

```
#create myfile.dot.png
dot -Tpng myfile.dot -O
```

Comment: Probably I was not clear in my question. I want a solution where I do not have to install GraphViz on my computer. I need a jar only solution. Where I can include some jars on my classpath and use the graph api (both for creating graph from my objects and then showing it to the user by drawing)

Comment: As soon as I posted I reread your question and realizes I was not addressing your request. Sorry about that. I think you were clear and I just missed it.